# DataGrid no type restriction on input

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

DataGrid columns are type locked. If you try and input a string into a column which is expecting an Int, you get the following error message.

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  'example
>   string' in ItemNo Column. Expected type is Int32.

The goal behind this is to be able to upload data from a CSV in any format, and have the datagrid accept it. The itemsource is bound to a source DataTable to ensure that the right amount of columns are autogenerated, as well as to get the columnnames to populate the ComboBox header

[image]

Does anyone know a way to allow for flexible input inside of a dataGrid?

Comment: Didn't I suggest either a DataTable or `ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>`? I think you were the guy. Make all the columns or properties strings, and you're good. In setting up CSV import, column value type validation could be a discreet step.

Comment: besides using object as type?

Comment: I got bored at two.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880021/datagrid-for-import-with-drop-down-column-headers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885086/changing-column-based-on-header-combobox-selection

Answer (score 1):

Usually being type safe and some validation is considered a good thing.

Bind itemssource to a collection of some type that has all it's public properties of type string. Then you can type what you want in each of them.

Comment: Note to OP, this may solve your temporary problem, but its almost guaranteed that you need some sort of validation. You should focus on Andy's first line over the rest or you'll just keep running into problems in the not so distant future. I.E. Even if you accept the string that expects an Int32, how do you know that value is valid?

Comment: I appended the question. I have the tables ItemSource bound already. I use that source to populate the Headers of each column with a ComboBox populated by all the column names.

Comment: Well that's just great but users are likely to type complete junk in if you let them,

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before?

Comment: They'll be importing from a CSV. The CSV's used don't have a consistent template. so some of the columns need to be redirected.